# Open offline html file programmatically in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, app-offline.htm, offline-browsing

I am building an application in windows phone 7. I have some user guide in HTML. I want to use a web-browser to open these files whenever user touches Help menu. But I don't know how to get the local URLs of these files. Could you help me please?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can navigate to HTML stored in isolated storage using a Relative Uri. More details and sample code here.

[How to: Display Static Web Content Using the WebBrowser Control for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431811%28VS.92%29.aspx)